# Python BeautifulSoup Decoding HTML entities

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
file_txt = urllib.request.urlopen("ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1220985/0000930413-12-003922.txt")
file = file_txt.read().decode('cp1252')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
print(soup.prettify())
#UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 11900: character maps to <undefined>
```

I checked the txt file. When it is displayed in the browser, `\x92` actually displays as the HTML entity `&#146` for `'`. I am not sure why the error occurs after I decode it using the same encoding scheme (`cp1252`) as that of my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `BeautifulSoup` is good at detecting the encoding used by a web page, and it do that by using the [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet/1.0.1) library if it's available. So i will suggest you to install the [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet/1.0.1) package and to let `BeautifulSoup` figure out the encoding.

```
pip install chardet (or easy_install chardet)
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Python 3 which supposedly has full support for unicode. The package you recommended was a bit old for Python 3.

Comment: @zsljulius: Python3 have better unicode support doesn't mean that he have the feature of sniffing encoding that what ``chardet`` package is for, IMHO. May i ask, did you try it ?

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup reads the document, but when you try to print it to the console you get an error. This generally indicates that your console can't display a certain character. [This page on the Python wiki may help.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails)

Comment: I also tried to write the output to a file. Same issue with the UnicodeError